# GWT - How to get a value and decide which page load

Tags: gwt, get

I need to know (by using GWT) the strategy of how load some class instead of some others according to HTTP GET value.

Example :

```
// Main.gwt.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <entry-point class="org.sinfonet.client.PageLoader"/>
</module>

// PageLoader
package org.sinfonet.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class PageLoader implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        FlowPanel pageloader=new FlowPanel();
        pageloader.add(new MainHomePage());
        RootPanel.get().add(pageloader);
    }
}
```

If my `GET` is `http://localhost:8084/GWT/index.html`, i would like to load `MainHomePage()`;

Else, if my `GET` is `http://localhost:8084/GWT/index.html?page=2`, i would like to load `MainAnotherClass()`;

I need to implements this on PageLoader class, on XML, or where? I think on xml, because PageLoader is a client-side class...there is no way to take a decision here.

P.S. I want to load another page (alias, another main Class), not load it dinamically.

**EXAMPLE I TRIED**

Thanks to `Chris Boesing` of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-gwt) solution, i found an easy piece of code that do what i need. Unfortunatly somethings is wrong, because it call the `.clear()` method, but it doesnt append my new container. That's the code :

```
public class PageLoader implements EntryPoint, ValueChangeHandler<String> {
    private FlowPanel pageloader;
    private GWTServiceAsync rpcService;

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        pageloader=new FlowPanel();
        rpcService=GWT.create(GWTService.class);
        pageloader.add(new HomepageContext(rpcService));
        RootPanel.get().add(pageloader);

        History.addValueChangeHandler(this);
        if(!History.getToken().isEmpty()){
            changePage(History.getToken());
        }
    }

    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        changePage(History.getToken());
    }

    public void changePage(String token) {
        if(History.getToken().equals("apartment")) {
            pageloader.clear();
            pageloader.add(new ApartmentContext(rpcService));
        } else {
            pageloader.clear();
            pageloader.add(new HomepageContext(rpcService));
        }
    }    
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I believe the servlet container is the program that chooses which page to load based on the URL.  I don't even know if this is possible but it would depend on what server you are using?  are you using Tomcat? GAE? JBoss?

Comment: Tomcat :) But which is the main servlet in GWT? I think i cant manage  it directly with GWT, or maybe i dont know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you should first add a servlet (instead of the static html page) to serve your gwt application.

First step could be just add a servlet that return the current static html page with gwt iframe. You need also to change your web.xml of course.

Second step is to change the returned html according the url to show one gwt module or the other.
This is the only solution if you want to show 2 different gwt applications (aka modules) according the url.

Anyway if I understood your question, what you want to do is just show different data using the url, for that I recommend another solution: use the # sign.

It's very easy with GWT to show different pages (inside a single GWT module) with this syntax.
http://localhost:8084/GWT/index.html
http://localhost:8084/GWT/index.html#page=2
http://localhost:8084/GWT/index.html#searchFor=foo
etc.

look for Events and History in GWT documentation.
This is also a very good starting point to have RESTish urls:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Comment: Uhm...i don't know if i have well understand that articles...but i don't think that is what i need! I need to load a new "page" when i get the value from the GET (not load others class instead of which i have). I think this is possible in GWT, right? In fact i would like to "change" the context, like swith page in the old web application approch (load apartment.php instead of index.php , do you know what i mean?). But i have to think about this, because maybe on GWT is better use its own methodology :)

Comment: In gwt there are no "page", technically all the gwt application is a single page, so adding another page it means adding another gwt application (a module with a different entry point). This is what I specified in the first part of the answer.

Comment: I think that you only want to change the current page, without actually leaving it. To do that you just need to work in the page DOM.

  private void loadWelcomeView() {
    final Label welcomeMsg = new Label("welcome");
    welcomeMsg.addStyleName("welcomeMsg");
    RootPanel.get().clear();
    RootPanel.get().add(welcomeMsg);
  }

for example this code will remove everything it was in the page and replace with the label.

You have to call this method when user click a button or insert a url (look at GWT History and Events)

Comment: Yes, in fact im working with this method. What i dont like if that i need to create ALL code on client-side and upload from the server to the client, or call runAsyncCall method to upload it only when I need it. Else, it's a waste of resource, no?

Comment: If you don't need all the code in the first call, you can use a technique called CodeSplitting that allows you to load the code only when you need it. 
See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html

Answer (score 3):

i think you'll want to implement a ValueChangeHandler< String > , and work with History ( History.addValueChangeHandler( changeHandler ).

then, on your valuechangehandler implementation you can get the token requested and choose what view to show.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Uhm..this approch is not so clear for me. So i've added an example, maybe you can help me, if you have time and patient :) thanks for your effort!