# Remove index.html GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, indexing

Hy , 
    I am creating an login/logout system with GWT.
    User is prompted with index.html , enters user , pass , server verify`s it and sands back true or false , this part is done and working.
    Now i am creating a widget for an administration part.
    If the response is true i would like to send him to administration widget , i created that too , and works.
    The problem is that the login screen does not disappear when i use

```
  RootPanel.get().add(widget);
```

And i would like to "hide" all the login part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [Multiple pages tutorial in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-google-web-toolkit-gwt/1063875#1063875)

It goes over how to have multiple "pages" within the context of GWT.  The guide is a little out of date but should help move in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't just wrap all the login stuff in a giant `div` and have GWT add a style which has `display:none` when the login is successful?

Comment: i could do that , i`ll try it

Answer (score 0):

Widgets will be in the DOM until detached (removed). You'll need to manually remove the widget. Adding another widget will not remove the preceding widget.

```
RootPanel.get().remove(myWidget);
```

Or add a class to it:

```
myWidgetInstantiation.getStyle().setVisible(VISIBILITY.Hidden);
```