# How do we navigate from 1 page to another in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am building a project in GWT and the project requires navigation from one page to another when a button is clicked. How do I do this? Or should I simply write the entire code in the same class file? I know there has to be a way of navigation.

How should I achieve page navigation in GWT?

Comment: Search for GWT presenters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple pages tutorial in Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061705/multiple-pages-tutorial-in-google-web-toolkit-gwt)

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [GWT Platform](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/)

With this library, you can define **places**. When the user clicks on a button, you just **reveal a new place**.

In addition, this framework allows you to handle the lifecycle of your GWT components and do some **code splitting** : page 1 and page 2 can be compiled in 2 different js so that you only load the one you need.

it is also a (and mainly) a **MVP framework**, like **gwt-presenter**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do Page navigation through [History](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics.html#DevGuideHistory) mechanism of GWT. Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Add a history string to an `iframe` of your host page:
2. Register a `ValueChangeHandler` that will receive an event of history (page) change. Within this handler you need put a logic that displays the new page.
   For example, `History.addValueChangeHandler(object of subclass of HistoryHandler);`
3. After doing this whenever you need to navigate to another page do the following: `History.newItem("history string of your page to be displayed");`

Comment: Please click on the text in blue which says "History" in RAS's reply. It is a hyperlink and will provide you all the details you require

Comment: @maneesh thanks for saying this. My answer to the richim's comment is the same.

Comment: @richim, Please go through the link & then tell me what you didn't understand?